# D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

Tags: android

I have a problem and i don't know how to solve it. Anyone with an idea of how to solve this?

```
07-05 10:12:15.449 16055-16055/com.emeraldcodes.apk W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.emeraldcodes.apk-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.emeraldcodes.apk-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-05 10:12:17.270 16055-16055/com.emeraldcodes.apk W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.emeraldcodes.apk-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.emeraldcodes.apk-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-05 10:12:17.370 16055-16055/com.emeraldcodes.apk W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.emeraldcodes.apk-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.emeraldcodes.apk-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-05 10:12:17.462 16055-16055/com.emeraldcodes.apk W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.emeraldcodes.apk-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.emeraldcodes.apk-1@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-05 10:12:17.547 16055-16055/com.emeraldcodes.apk W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.emeraldcodes.apk-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.emeraldcodes.apk-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-05 10:12:17.626 16055-16055/com.emeraldcodes.apk W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.emeraldcodes.apk-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.emeraldcodes.apk-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-05 10:12:17.721 16055-16055/com.emeraldcodes.apk W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.emeraldcodes.apk-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.emeraldcodes.apk-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-05 10:12:17.814 16055-16055/com.emeraldcodes.apk W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.emeraldcodes.apk-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.emeraldcodes.apk-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-05 10:12:17.917 16055-16055/com.emeraldcodes.apk W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.emeraldcodes.apk-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.emeraldcodes.apk-1@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-05 10:12:18.027 16055-16055/com.emeraldcodes.apk W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.emeraldcodes.apk-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.emeraldcodes.apk-1@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-05 10:12:18.108 16055-16055/com.emeraldcodes.apk W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a7 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.emeraldcodes.apk-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.emeraldcodes.apk-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-05 10:12:18.119 16055-16055/com.emeraldcodes.apk W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.emeraldcodes.apk-1/lib/arm
07-05 10:12:18.152 16055-16065/com.emeraldcodes.apk I/System: FinalizerDaemon: finalize objects = 1
07-05 10:12:18.177 16055-16055/com.emeraldcodes.apk D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-05 10:12:18.579 16055-16055/com.emeraldcodes.apk I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 16055 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to do some steps:-

1. Just clear the "app\build\intermediates\split-apk" folder
2. Disable Instant run in android studio
3. Run app again.